# How to set values of DOM elements with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, puppeteer

How to set specific values of the DOM with Puppeteer?

**i.e:**

> b = document.querySelector("button");

- `b.innerHTML = 'value';`
- `b.setAttribute('specific-attr', 'value');`

Comment: Use `page.evaluate` if you want to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the innerHTML:

`await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('button').innerHTML = 'value');`

For the specific attribute:

`await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('button').setAttribute('specific-attr', 'value'));`